# Property IncreaseValue by reflection

Tags: c#, .net

i'm need to know how to add a value to a property using reflection
example i have property with name Health
i want to increase the value by 10

```
var prop = typeof (Character).GetProperty(actionParams.PropertyName);
var oldValue = (int)prop.GetValue(client.Character);
prop.SetValue(client.Character, Convert.ChangeType((oldValue + 10), prop.PropertyType));
```

but i get cast error

> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: On which line? Post the exception. and What was the `PropertyType`?

Comment: what are you using exactly? this seems to be called from a method delegate or something with a param, and you seem to juggle types ... why is that? don't you know what type it is to begin with?

Comment: Show us enough of your code that we can copy/paste it to reproduce it.

Comment: Please show the definition of the `Character` class.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your property with name `Health` is not of type `int`, so the cast `(int)prop.GetValue(client.Character);` fails.

Comment: i know why this error is happening i just want to know how to avoid it without using Casting since i want to edit many properties with different types.